# React Typescript MUI - multiple fonts in one theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use different fonts on different components.
I am trying to do something like this in customTheme.ts:

```
import {createTheme} from '@mui/material/styles'

...
  typography: {
    newFontFamily: [ //<-- added from here
      'Rubik-Medium',
      'Rubik-Regular',
      'Rubik-Bold',
      'Rubik-Light'
    ].join(','),     //<-- to here
    fontFamily: [
      'AreaNormal',
      'AreaNormal-Black',
      'AreaNormal-Bold',
      'AreaNormal-Semibold',
      'AreaNormal-Extrabold'
    ].join(',')
  }
})

export default Theme
```

To apply different fonts for different components:
`theme.typography.fontFamily`,
`theme.typography.newFontFamily`

But I`m receiving the following error:

```
Type '{ newFontFamily: string; fontFamily: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TypographyOptions | ((palette: Palette) => TypographyOptions) | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'newFontFamily' does not exist in type 'TypographyOptions | ((palette: Palette) => TypographyOptions)'.ts(2322)
```